# Quotas for Google Services of GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I am currently developing with GAS. And the limit of the number of executions became a problem. My account is Google Workspace.

What if the total number of executions by the trigger exceeds the limit?
And can't we increase that limit?

And what it mean "simultaneous executions"? Does that mean that the same script will be called at the same time? I couldn't understand it by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) are here. To my knowledge, you cannot go beyond these quotas using Apps Script.

Simultaneouse executions is maybe best explained as an example. Imagine you have a function which takes 30 seconds to run. This function could run 30 times within the same time frame but not 31. If you try to execute it a 31st time, even though 30 functions are still running / have not finished, then your 31st execution will throw an error. I have an API which handles document generation and this takes quite some time, therefore I add a delay in between calls in order for some executions to be finished.

Comment: Who does the restriction apply to? the Supplier of the addon / service or the end user account? To be more clear current limit is 30 simultaneous executions. assuming 1000 users are calling the same function 30 times ( total: 1000x30=30,000) Simultaneous executions for 1000 different users. would that work? also. if it at the function level it means one can call 30 time to `func1()` and another 30 times to `func2()` all at the same time. is that true?

Comment: @OJNSim who the quota applies to depends on who is running the application. If the function is to be run by the user, then it applies to each user and you should have the ability for 1 million users to use a function at the same time. In another case, where the script is an API, likely a particular user is running all requests and then you can only have 30 instances of the function running at one time.